# How do I determine the key that caused a textbox input event to fire?

Tags: javascript, input, dom-events, keypress

If I have a textbox,

```html
<input id='Sub' type='text'>
```

I can capture each time the input changes with:

```
sub = document.getElementById('Sub');
sub.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
    // here the contents of the textbox is accessible via this.value
    ...
}, false);
```

I'd like to identify when <kbd>backspace</kbd> and <kbd>delete</kbd> are the causes of input firing so I can handle them specially.  From what I can tell, neither `e`, nor `this` expose the key that was pressed to cause the input event to fire.  Is there any way to find out what the key was?

Comment: because the oninput event fires on many events, such as paste, change etc. it doesn't have keyCode/which as it makes no sense to have something like that for many of the actions that triggers the event, if you want that, use a key* event instead.

Answer (score 1):

"input" is not an event you want to capture. You have to catch "keypress" event. And then you can see "e.keyCode":

```
var sub = document.getElementById('Sub');
sub.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode)
}, false);
```

Here's a small demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9LZ9Z/

Comment: what if I want to capture pastes too?

Comment: But that wouldn't be a key would it (you can paste with mouse)?

Comment: right.  I want a function to run when the input event fires (whether due to a character press or paste), but not if it is from a <delete> or <backspace> event.  So I'd like to identify the <delete> and <backspace> keys in the function.

Comment: I suggest capturing separate events "keypress" (probably even "keydown" for more granular control) "paste" etc. and react to them accordingly, because their event objects provide different information.